# Can I fit parking sensors on the front of my car?

Tags: sensor, parking

I'm getting a reversing camera for the back of my car, as I often have to park in very tight spaces, or am parked in.
However, I can't fit a camera to the front, so I was wondering:

Can I fit rear parking sensors to the front of my 2003 Opel Agila?

Would I have to drill into the bumper?

Are there any caveats to this solution?

Comment: If you are going to use them as judgement, for parking and other things, i would suggest , attaching a stick or something to the front left side of the bumper to let you know the bonnet length , after a while you will know the length of the bonnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can put them in the front bumper. You'll need to drill them in - just like the back bumper.

I would recommend having a cut off switch for the front sensors somewhere in the cabin, otherwise the beeping would be very annoying. Rear sensors are (usually) powered by the reversing lamp's wiring, so in the front you won't have this... so a cut off switch is a requirement!

It will look a bit strange having them in the front!

Comment: I never use my fog lights, so if it were my car, I'd wire them up to those.